# How to retrieve hashmap values in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

How to retrieve values from the following hashmap in velocity template? Please help..

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Integer, Object>> hashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Integer,Object>>();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, add the hashmap to your backing Java class (reference [here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#The_Context)).

```
context.put("myhashmap", hashmap);
```

Then you can [reference](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#references) anywhere in your Velocity template, e.g:

```
<span>$myhashmap.get("foo").get(1).toString()</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$!myhashmap.get($!foo).toString();
```

Note: `foo` is a variable in my case.