# Creating a HashMap in Velocity Template

Tags: java, apache, velocity

I just cant find an example of how to create a HashMap in velocity. I want to create an empty HashMap and put values in it for later retrieval. Any help on this would be grateful.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Usually all the data is collected first and then pushed to the template. The template should only be responsible to present the data.

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16630586/294097

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Velocity Template engine - key-value-map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398116/velocity-template-engine-key-value-map)

Comment: This question has an example of declaration.  The answers will tell you jow to retrieve it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416034/how-to-retrieve-hashmap-values-in-velocity-template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

```
#set($myMap = {})
#set($map.foo = 'bar')
#set($map[1234] = 3456)
Map is: $map
```

This displays:

```
Map is: {foo=foo, 1234=1234}
```

The map is actually a `java.util.LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Yes it was a duplicate of the other question. The thread title was a little off, so didn't show up on searching. Thanks for the help guys!